# Fast binary diff for 10 MB files

Tags: linux, binary, diff

I have two 10 MB files, and I'd like to find the longest common subsequence with offsets, e.g. the result should look like:

```
42 bytes at offset 5 of the first file and offset 8 of the second file
85 bytes at offset 100 of the first file and offset 55 of the second file
...
```

This is a one-off-task, I have to run it only on a single pair of files.

I don't care about the programming language, but it must run on Linux.

I have tried command-line tools `bsdiff` and `xdelta`, but their output diff file format is too complicated to understand, and it lacks any documentation -- so I would have to understand complicated and undocumented C source code to get those results. It would take several hours, and I don't have that much time for this, so I'm giving up on that path.

I have tried Perl module String::LCSS_XS , but that's too slow (it has been running for an hour now), Perl module Algorithm::Diff::XS, but it needs too much memory, and Perl module Algorithm::LCSS, but that's too slow (implemented in Perl). I couldn't find anything useful in Python (the built-in difflib is too slow).

Is there a tool which runs quickly (i.e. less than a few hours) for 10 MB files, and I can convert its output to the format I want in less than an hour of work?

Comment: Is there a question here? Since you found tools that do part of the job, format their output.

Comment: None of the tools I mention in the question can do the job. I'm still looking for a good tool. I clarified the question.

Comment: do you require the LCS or a "good enough" diff would be correct? The tool I work for, ECMerge, would definitely produce the necessary data (on Linux both GUI/CLI, and a few calls to `System.Console.write` in Javascript would print what you need). Note that typical LCS based on Myers algo is in O(ND) which makes it impractical for large files but on trivially different. If you find an implementation based on Myers modified with suffix trees or suffix arrays you might be OK.